Diagonal directions for cuboid in 3/4 axonometric rpg view
In pixel art, how can I construct the diagonal directions for this cuboid?
The goal is to create an 8 directional turnaround for a 2D top-down game.

I am using the 3/4 rpg view, made popular through the 2D Pokemon games and old-school RPGs, such as Final Fantasy 6, Chrono Trigger, and Secret of Mana.
It is a parallel projection that is orthographic, axonometric and dimetric. The viewing angle is 45 deg. This results in depth shortening with a factor of 3/4 = 0.75 (which is simplified from the true value of sqrt(2)/2 = approx 0.707).
When it comes to representing objects that are turned by 45 degrees, i.e. rotating this object to create the diagonal directions, I believe I have 3 options:

Use the perfect 4:3 angle (36.87°), not resulting in a clean line (has jaggies)
Stylize to to 1:1 diagonals (45°), resulting in a clean line
Stylize to 2:1 diagonals (25.47°), resulting in a clean line

Given my scene context and type of gameplay, I believe option 2 will work best for me. However, I do not understand what rules I need to follow to draw the rotated object in practice.
Q: Given the front and side directions I currently have, how can I construct the diagonal directions to create an 8 directional turnaround?

Let's start by walking through what you get with option number 2:
Because of your \$\frac 3 4\$ foreshortening ratio, we can use this formula to take a line with some original length running left/right in the horizontal plane and get the pixel rise and run (delta_y and delta_x respectively) of its image rotated in the horizontal plane by a given angle:
delta_x = Round(Cos(angle) * original_length)

delta_y = Round(0.75 * Sin(angle) * original_length)

If we use 45° for our angle, we get two unequal values, breaking your 1:1 rule. So, we need to figure out the angle that will make these match:
$$
\cos \theta = \frac 3 4 \sin \theta\\
\frac 4 3 = \frac {\sin \theta} {\cos \theta} = \tan \theta\\
\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac 4 3\\
\theta \approx 53.13010235 ^{\circ}
$$
Plugging that angle into the formulas above, we get that the 32 pixel length of the bottom box should map to a 19:19 diagonal, and so on.
This isn't exactly volume-preserving. We've effectively replaced a rectangle in the horizontal plane with a parallelogram, slightly pinching the corners that point towards/away from us. They end up forming 90° in the image plane (with legs splaying off 45° to each side), meaning that if we undo the projection, the supposedly real 3D object we're drawing has angles of 180° - 2*53° = 74° here instead: significantly acute. That squishes the object in the left-right axis so that it loses volume, in exchange for preserving the correct foreshortened lengths of the edges.

Next, we can try option number 3 and open up to 2:1 diagonals. We'll repeat the calculation above to find the angles in the horizontal plane that give us a rise:run of 1:2 or 2:1:
$$\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
1&:2\\
\cos \theta &= 2 \left( \frac 3 4 \sin \theta \right)\\
\cos \theta &= \frac 3 2 \sin \theta\\
\frac 2 3 &= \tan \theta\\
\theta &= \tan^{-1} \frac 2 3\\
\theta &\approx 33.69006753^\circ
\end{aligned}
\quad \quad
\begin{aligned}
2&:1\\
2 \left(\cos \theta\right) &= \frac 3 4 \sin \theta \\
2 \frac 4 3 &= \tan \theta\\
\frac 8 3 &= \tan \theta\\
\theta &= \tan^{-1} \frac 8 3\\
\theta &\approx 69.44395478^\circ
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$
Now we have three different angles that we can represent with neat stairstep patterns: 34°, 53°, and 69°. Nice.
If we try subtracting pairs of these angles from 180°, we find that drawing one leg at a 53° angle (1:1) and one leg at a 34° angle (1:2) gives us very close to 90° in between - we overshoot by about 3° instead of the 16° undershoot we get when using only 1:1 diagonals.
Using the formulas at the top with these angles gives something like this:

The result is much closer to volume-preserving, but it does visibly lean closer to one cardinal direction or the other, depending on which  edge you choose to draw with the 1:2 ratio. So you'll have to pick between turning "slightly too much" or "slightly too little". (Or switch to a 12-direction system to have your cake and eat it too, at the cost of 33-50% more asset creation)

Thank you! I will try to replicate this. I am not interested in option 1 because the edges would have jaggies as far as I understand. But I am curious about option 3 because I think it will preserve the volume. How would I need to change the formulas for that?

I've updated the answer to show what option 3 could look like, and the angles to plug into the formulas to get your rise and run values for 2:1 and 1:2 diagonals.

Thank you for updating your answer! I am trying to replicate this myself. You said "Plugging that angle [53 deg] into the formulas above, we get that the 32 pixel length of the bottom box should map to a 19:19 diagonal, and so on." I don't understand how to replicate your result. Plugging in the angle, I get delta_x = -30 and delta_y = 6.5, not 19. Please can you elaborate?

Sounds like your function is expecting an input in radians and you're giving it an input in degrees. Try converting to radians first (multiply the degree angle by $ \frac \pi {180^{\circ}} $).
